# How to make every ID in a database unique

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables called Teachers, Admin and Students and they all have an ID. How do I make it so that none of their IDs are the same.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want this?

Comment: @Heijden I require this because my assignment requires that every user in the system have a unique ID.

Comment: And what are the difference between them? If non, use a `Users` table with a `Role` or `UserType` column.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Ron in his comment, perhaps the easiest option here would be to just use a single users table with a role column, something like this:

```
id | role
1  | teacher
2  | student
3  | student
4  | admin
```

However, it is also fairly straightforward for you to continue using three separate tables for the teachers, students, and admins.  You can logically make their IDs unique by just appending a prefix to each number, e.g. `A123` is the 123rd admin, while `S46` is the 46th student.

Comment: How would I append a prefix?

Comment: @user372834 in mysql, use [concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) like `select concat('A', AdminID) from Admins`